# Cypress: login with multiple accounts - fixture

Tags: cypress, fixtures

How can I access multiple accounts in a fixture file?
the aim is to login multiple websites with different accounts:

```
[
    {
       "url": "https://www.Atest.com/",        
        "username": "Atest",
        "password": "Test123!"
    },
    
    {

        "url": "https://www.Btest.com/",
        "username": "Btest",
        "password": "Test123!"

    }

]
```

Comment: You want to do all the login within a single test or you want to create different tests for different logins?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this if you want everything under one test

```js
describe('Test Suite', () => {
  it('Test Case', () => {
    cy.readFile('cypress/fixtures/details.json').then((details) => {
      details.forEach((detail) => {
        cy.visit(detail.url)
        cy.get('#username').type(detail.username)
        cy.get('#username').type(detail.password)
      })
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works! I've been stuck on this for weeks. I was using cy.fixture instead of  cy.readFile